# hide ion-tabs/ ion-tab-bar in a specific tab page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i am building a stanalone ionic angular application, the routing works. but i want to hide the tabbar at the bottom when i navigate into a certain tab page, because i want to render a chatbox componente here.

tabs.page.html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <img id="animation" [src]="tabStatus['tab2'].image" (click)="onClickTab('tab2')" alt="..." >
    </ion-tab-button>

    ....

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

tab2.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule,CommonModule],
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  constructor() {   }
 


}
```

i guess that i have to specify in the respective ts file, here tab2.page.ts, the respective module or something specific to signaulize that they ion-tabs should not be imported here. also i don't know if i can just hide them possibly by css commands.

about solutions I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

You can hide tabs based on your routing:

> tabs.page.ts

```
import { Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';

isChatPage: boolean = false;

constructor(
    private router:Router
  ) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      if(event && event.url== 'yourChatPageUrl'){
        this.isChatPage = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

> tabs.page.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isChatPage">
   <ion-tabs>
     /* your tabs code here*/
   </ion-tabs>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your page independent from the tabs and navigate there with click event. here is an example with defining the page at '/chats':

```
<ion-tab-button (click)="onClickTab('tab2')">
      <img id="animation" [src]="tabStatus['tab2'].image" alt="..." >
</ion-tab-button>
```

and in typescript:

```
onClickTab(tab: string){
    if(tab === 'tab2'){
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/chats');
    }
}
```

in case you are not familiar with navController, you need to define that as well:

```
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
...
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
```

but generally I don't recommend having a tab button that leads to a page with no tab bar, it's bad UX.